# Docker postgres work_mem not using ram

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have set `shared_buffers` to 256MB.

Using `pg_buffercache` extension I see that all of the buffers are in use:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(COUNT(*)*8192) as used FROM pg_buffercache;
 used
----------------
 256 MB
```

Now the problem is that when I use docker stats to view the database container memory it shows:

```
NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM % 
db                  0.00%               31.07MiB / 1GiB     3.03%
```

Where is the `shared_buffers` memory stored? Shouldn't be in ram and displayed in `docker stats`?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `work_mem`, of course.

pg_buffercache has one row for every buffer slot, whether it has ever been used for anything or not.  Use `count(relfileode)`, not `count(*)`, to count just the ones that are actually used.

I don't think there is any way with pg_buffercache to get the high water mark, the closest might be something like:

```
select max(bufferid) from pg_buffercache where relfilenode is not null;
```

But that will give too low an answer (for your purposes) if all the highest numbered bufferid belonged to a table that got dropped or truncated, for example.

Comment: Note that if I do a group by `relfilenode`: `SELECT relfilenode::regclass::text, COUNT(*)*8192 FROM pse.pg_buffercache group by relfilenode::regclass::text` I get usage by table and if I sum them I get the same issue, higher than reported ram usage.

Comment: GROUP BY doesn't remove NULLs, it just generates a group for them.